# What does exterior product has to do with Determinant?

Tags: determinant, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

Gravitation By Charles Misner, Kip Thorene, John Wheeler page 129.

The components of the exterior product of $p$ vectors

$\displaystyle
(\cal u_1\wedge u_2\wedge...\wedge u_p)^{\alpha_1...\alpha_p}
=...
=p!u_1^{[\alpha_1}u_2^{\alpha_2}...u_p^{\alpha_p]}
=\delta^{\alpha_1\alpha_2...\alpha_p}_{1,2...p}\det[(u_\mu)^\lambda]$

Some related information could be found here. [Determinant and Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Levi-Civita_symbol) But still, I'm a bit confused of why exterior product could be so closely connected to determinant.

Is it because Levi-Civita symbol could be computed from the determinate of Kronecker delta? Does this carry any further implications?

(A related reference could be found here: [Product of Levi-Civita symbol is determinant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946493/product-of-levi-civita-symbol-is-determinant) where guestDiego's answer provided some insights.)

Comment: If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space, then its $n$-th exterior product 
$\bigwedge^n V$ is a one-dimensional vector space. A linear map
$T:V\to V$ induces a linear map $\bigwedge^n T:\bigwedge^n V\to\bigwedge^n V$.
Then $\bigwedge^n T$ is just multiplication by $\det T$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That looks pretty much like an answer to me.